# Extending the Content Search web part; adding more fields & change the display template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web-part, display-template, content-search-web-part

I am working on a sharepoint server 2013 enterprise edition. and i have 2 site collections; `http://servername/` & `http://servername/depts` . where the later site collection contain multiple sub sites.
Now I want to use the Content search we part inside the `http://servername` site collection to show items from different sub sites inside the `http://servername/dept` site collection.

So i follow these steps:-

- I went to my site collection `http://servername/`
- Edit the home page, add a new Content search web part.
- I define the following query to mainly show all the items that are associated with the related issue tracking content type and are under the `http://servername/dept` url:-

[image]

- then i define the following to show the title, created & site tile fields for each item.

[image]

- Finally the output i got inside the content search webpart is as follow:-

[image]

now i am still not sure how i can do the following 2 modifications:-

1. add more fields beside the title, created & site title?
2. how i can show the fields in a table based view, so each item will have its fields shown in a single row, rather than showing the item's fields under each other (as shown above) ?

so can anyone adivce how i can achieve my above 2 modifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **Display Templates** you can change the way you want to display results of content serach web part.

You can find a variety of Display Templates at this [link](https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates)

To have table based view, please follow these steps.

1. Copy `Control_List_Table.html` & `Item_List_Item.html` files from this [link](https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Multi%20Sort%20Templates%20(CSWP)) and paste into this path `~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Template/Content Web Part/`
2. Publish all the copied files to their major versions.
3. Now Edit Content Search Web part. In Display Template section, select `List Table Control` for `Control` and `List Table Item` for `Item` dropdown.
4. Now you will be able to see, multiple properties in `Property Mapping` section where you can map multiple Managed Property which will be displayed as columns in tabular view of search results.

Customize these display templates as per your need.

Here are some references on display templates:

[SharePoint 2013 Customize Display Template for Content By Search Web Part (CSWP)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1/)

[Content Search Web Part: Custom Display Templates](http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/content-search-web-parts-custom-display-templates)

[SharePoint 2013 Design Manager display templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the links will have a look at them,, never thought that i can download ready temples instead of having to build them from scratch

Comment: I have used these display templates before and they are simply awesome. Great work has been done by author of those display templates.

Comment: i also found this link https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Sorting%20Templates%20(CSWP) i tried the   Control_List_Table.html & Item_List_Item.html .. seems they are great and provide sorting capabilities also

Comment: I have tried this above solution, and it does not populate to my Content Search WP, I click control and it is the basic three List, List with Paging, Slideshow. I hard refreshed F5 and that still did not solve it